# Open Excel file through Outlook VBA and set focus of it to be in front

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I open an Excel file through Outlook VBA but it is in the background (behind the Outlook application).

I tried `AppActivate`, but it raises this error:

> Invalid procedure call or argument

```vb
Public Sub Open_Excel_File()
    Dim xExcelFile As String
    Dim xExcelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xWb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xWs As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xExcelRange As Excel.Range
 
    xExcelFile = "xxxxx"   ' Path to the Excel File
 
    Set xExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xWb = xExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(xExcelFile)
    Set xWs = xWb.Sheets(1)
    xWs.Activate
    Set xExcelRange = xWs.Range("A2")
    xExcelRange.Activate
    xExcelApp.Visible = True
    AppActivate xWb.Windows(1).Caption
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd recommend changing the order in which the `Visible` property and `Activate` method are called:

```
    Set xExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xWb = xExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(xExcelFile)
    Set xWs = xWb.Sheets(1)
    xWs.Activate
    Set xExcelRange = xWs.Range("A2")
    xExcelApp.Visible = True
    xWs.Activate
```

Typically that is enough.

---

Second, you may use Windows API functions to bring the window to the foreground. The [SetForegroundWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow) function brings the thread that created the specified window into the foreground and activates the window.

```
#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" _
               (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" _
               (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
#End If
```

So your code could look like that:

```
Public Sub Bring_to_front()
    Dim setFocus As Long

    xWs.Activate
    setfocus = SetForegroundWindow(xExcelApp.hwnd)
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your both options exactly as your answer. The first one `xWs.Activate` has no effect ( excel file still behind outlook application).
The second option **API** works perfectly, even without using xWs.Activate.
The code on my question are found on outlook separate module (not Thisoutlooksession) and firing through a custom button on Ribbon.
grateful for your fully descriptive answer 